# "like it like you" vs "like it, like you"

Tags: commas, formality, comprehension

My husband and I have discussed for an hour over this and we still haven’t agreed. Please help!

Do these two sentences have different meanings?

> (A) She doesn’t like it like you.
>
> (B) She doesn’t like it, like you.

Comment: Yes, they have different meanings. #1 involves an ellipsis: in full, it would be "she doesn't like it like you *do*", and means "she doesn't like it in the way that you like it" (i.e. you like it in a different way to her). #2 means "she doesn't like it. You don't like it either."

Answer (score 1):

I find the first one a bit odd, but yes, it has a different meaning.

The first one is a comparison: she doesn't like it in the way, or to the degree, that you do. It is not even saying that she doesn't like it: just not in the way, or as much as, you do.

The second is a categorical statement, and an additional comment. She doesn't like it, and in that respect she is like you.

Comment: The first wording I would suggest means that "she doesn't like (the bacon?) as much as she likes you". To arrive at your meaning she would need to say "She doesn't like it like you do".

Comment: @WS2 - I think many speakers would elide (or is it omit?) the "do"; I can certainly agree with Colin's meaning being a possibility.

Comment: @AndyT Many speakers might. But I don't think I would.

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree that the second sentence means:

> As is the case with you, she doesn't like it either.

---

I agree that already suggested interpretation of the first sentence is a possibility:

> She doesn't like it **in the way** you (do).

But when I first read the question, that's not the first thing that came to my mind. Instead, I had a different interpretation.

In this case, what I thought of is possible because of the multiple meanings of the word *like*—and, for some reason, I naturally assign it a different meaning in its second use in the first sentence.

Think of the following:

> John: "What does Mary think of that ventriloquist dummy I made for myself?
>   Sue: "She doesn't like it like you."

In other words:

> She doesn't like it **being** like you.
>   She doesn't like it **looking** like you.
>   She doesn't like it **acting** like you.
>   She doesn't like it **being similar** to you.
>   She doesn't like it **faithfully representing** you.

---

But however the first sentence is interpreted, I think it clearly has a different meaning than the second sentence.